# django-viewflow, rest api saving foreign key says "<ProcessName> has no <ForeignModel>"

Tags: django-viewflow

I have the following models setup:

```py
class Cluster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...


class ResourceRequest(Process):
    cluster = models.ForeignKey('Cluster')

    def clean(self, ...):
        if self.cluster.name == 'abc':
            ...
```

And when I try to post to:

http://pmas-local:8000/workflow/api/tasks/vm_request/resourcerequest/start/

it complains that `ResourceRequest has no cluster.`

Stacktrace shows `if self.cluster.name == 'abc':` caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to django-viewflow. That's standard django error for a foreign key field, which means that self.cluster is None.